# How can one exclude requests with no initiator from declarativeNetRequest rules?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm creating declarativeNetRequest rules and I'm having trouble excluding requests with no initiator from those rules (using chrome version `112.0.5615.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)`). An example use case is if a user manually enters a url directly into the address bar, the rules should not intercept the request.

I've tried excluding the following without success:

```js
excludedInitiatorDomains: ["", "null", "newtab", "localhost", "about:blank", "chrome://"]
```

I know that `chrome.runtime.id` works for requests initiated by the extension, but I'm not sure how to exclude requests initiated by the user or browser. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

MCVE:

**manifest.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "Chrome Extension Initiator Domain MCVE",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*.google.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

**rules.json**

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "action": { "type": "block" },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "google.com",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"],
      "excludedInitiatorDomains": ["google.com", "", "null", "newtab", "localhost", "about:blank", "chrome://"]
    }
  }
]
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug.addListener(info =>
    console.log(info)
)
```

Here is what gets logged when opening a new tab and directly navigating to `google.com`:

```json
{
    "request": {
        "documentLifecycle": "active",
        "frameId": 0,
        "frameType": "outermost_frame",
        "method": "GET",
        "parentFrameId": -1,
        "requestId": "72065",
        "tabId": 852200437,
        "type": "main_frame",
        "url": "https://www.google.com/"
    },
    "rule": {
        "ruleId": 1,
        "rulesetId": "ruleset_1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate this: Have you tried using [chrome.declarativeNetRequest > onRuleMatchedDebug](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#event-onRuleMatchedDebug) to look at the initiator for these requests? Then you don't have to try random strings!

Comment: AFAIK There are no requests without an initiator. The site itself becomes the initiator in the cases you've described.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm actually already excluding the current domain itself from initiator domains and that doesn't appear to solve this.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Correction, the initiator property is left out entirely.

Comment: Perhaps we're on different versions of chrome and therefore experiencing different behavior, but `onRuleMatchedDebug`'s `MatchedRuleInfoDebug.initiator` is entirely left out for me when I enter the url directly into the address bar of a new tab. I will work on getting a complete reproducible example when I have a moment.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've updated to question to add an MCVE.

Comment: Indeed, there's no `initiator` with your rules so you can't exclude it. If the goal is to whitelist your own extension's request you can use a higher `priority` in a second rule and an action of `allow`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Whitelisting extension requests is doable using `"excludedInitiatorDomains": [chrome.runtime.id]`, but that's not what's being discussed here. The question here is how to whitelist the user's requests or any other requests that don't have an initiator.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear. To reiterate: what you want is not possible and I suggested a workaround that may be usable depending on your goal which I don't know yet.

Comment: @EfraimBart - What wOxxOm is trying to tell you: You're asking about your attempted _solution_ rather than your actual _problem_. In other words, you've fallen into the [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) trap. Please go to the link, read the text, and then come back and tell us what problem you're trying to solve. Why am I telling you this? Because I have an idea that might work. But I'm 99% sure that if I go ahead and post the idea, you'll just say "oh, that's not what I want, because <insert reasons here>". That would be very frustrating, so I want more information first.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I've given an example use case, is that not helpful? Very simply, my goal is to redirect specific requests but I would not like to redirect them if they are entered directly by the user in the address bar.

Comment: There are potentially other cases without an initiator that I'd like to exclude as well, but this is a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change `rules.json`

- Instead of "excludedInitiatorDomains", use "initiatorDomains"
- List all valid TLDs

In the following example, I've only listed three common TLDs.
But I've also tried it with a list of ~1400 TLDs (only the ASCII ones) and a few country-specific search engines as the initiators.
There were no complaints from Chromium 112.0.5615.165 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit)

Get the complete TLD list from [IANA > Database of Top Level Domains > Hint and Zone Files > Top-Level Domains](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/files)

You must encode non-ASCII domains with [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), or Chrome will refuse to load the extension:
[chrome.declarativeNetRequest > RuleCondition > initiatorDomains](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#property-RuleCondition-initiatorDomains)

This is probably the only way to accomplish what you want, unless you're willing to use "webRequestBlocking".

rules.json

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "action": { "type": "block" },
        "condition": {
            "urlFilter": "google.com",
            "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"],
            "initiatorDomains": [
                "com",
                "net",
                "org"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Wow, this is crazy, but I'll definitely be giving it a try!

Comment: Other than not knowing another way, do you have a reason to think this is the only way?

Comment: Tested and working!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this is to redirect to an extension html page with javascript that checks the `document.referrer` to determine whether the original page is allowed and should therefore be navigated to.

**redirect.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>redirect</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/redirect.js"/>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

**redirect.js**

```js
const redirect = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("redirect")
if (!document.referrer) {
    window.location.href = redirect
}
```

**rules.json**

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "action": {
        "type": "redirect", 
        "redirect": {
            "regexSubstitution": `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/redirect.html?redirect=\\0`
        }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "google.com",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"],
      "excludedInitiatorDomains": [chrome.runtime.id]
    }
  }
]
```

This is not an amazing way to go about this, and it requires that the extension be whitelisted as an initiator domain, but it works.